# Contrib directory in PostgreSQL 9.1

Tags: centos, postgresql, postgis

Where is the contrib directory in PostgreSQL 9.1?

This [source](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/RPM_Installation) states its at `/usr/share/pgsql/contrib` but the directory `/usr/share/pgsql` does not exist. I installed PostgreSQL from the rpm, on a CentOS 6.3.

I am basically trying to find the correct location to find `/usr/share/pgsql/contrib/postgis-64.sql`

Comment: `/usr/pgsql-9.1/share/extension/` on my installations

Comment: When I install Postgres91 and contrib from the PGDG repo on CentOS 6, the contrib files/binaries are installed into `/usr/pgsql-9.1`, alongside the server package's binaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# yum whatprovides /usr/share/pgsql/contrib
...
Reading version lock configuration
Importing additional filelist information
postgresql-contrib-8.1.23-1.el5_7.3.x86_64 : Contributed source and binaries distributed with PostgreSQL
Repo        : base
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/share/pgsql/contrib
```